# Validate {} value before assign to model

Tags: c#

I have a query where I get data from database like this

```
var progressToBackCheck = (
    from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows 
    where timeOfTasks.Columns.Contains("ProgressToBackCheck") 
    select dr["ProgressToBackCheck"]
).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then I assign it to a model like:

```
 model.ProgressToBackCheck = (int?)progressToBackCheck;
```

But for some reason sometimes it comes with empty value like:

[image]

I try to validate it in `if` conditional like:

```
if (progressToBackCheck == null || progressToBackCheck == string.Empty || 
    progressToBackCheck.Equals("{}"))
{
    progressToBackCheck = 0;
}
```

But none work. What is `{}` supposed to mean? How can I validate it?

Comment: That's an empty object. You should be able to check against `DbNull.Value`

Comment: Works. Thankyou so much! @CamiloTerevinto